# JavaScript classes which cannot be subclassed

Tags: javascript, class, oop, final

I have a JavaScript class, and I would like to make it so it can't be subclassed. (Similar to marking a class with the "final" keyword in Java.) Here's my JavaScript class:

```
function Car(make, model) {
     this.getMake = function( ) { return make; }
     this.getModel = function( ) { return model; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The JavaScript Object Oriented paradigm is [prototype based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), that means that objects *"inherit"* from other objects, using them as their prototype.

There are no classes, `Car` is a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function), and the language lets you extend any virtually *any* object.

If you can make a `Car` object instance, there is no way to prevent this object being used as the prototype of other constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

Given that JavaScript doesn't even actually have classes (it's a prototype-based object system, not a class-based one), and that it is a dynamic language[1], what you want to do is impossible.  Further, JavaScript doesn't actually have inheritance/subclassing - it has to be faked by copying and extending objects.  There is no way (that I know of) to prevent other code from doing this.

1. In a dynamic language with metaclass support, it would be possible to implement such a feature.  JavaScript is not such a language.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't do this directly and don't know that there is a way to do this given Javascript's prototypical inheritance but take a look at [Extjs](http://www.extjs.com/), which is a js framework which has a heavy object oriented type design. Look at the api and more so the source code and you might get closer to where you want to go -- but not totally :)